# Yeoman task not copying directory

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to build a simple yeoman task that copies a template directory into the destination directory where the user is running the command. The prompt method is working but nothing is being written or copied. Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

```
'use strict';
//Require dependencies
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = class extends yeoman {
    //Ask for user input
    prompting() {
        var done = this.async();
        this.prompt({
            type: 'input',
            name: 'name',
            message: 'Your project name',
            //Defaults to the project's folder name if the input is skipped
            default: this.appname
        }, function(answers) {
            this.props = answers
            this.log(answers.name);
            done();
        }.bind(this));
    }

    //Writing Logic here
    writing() {
        this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath('testfile'),
            this.destinationPath('testfile')
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The prompt method doesn't take a callback since release 1.0

Instead you want `this.prompt([...]).then(callback)`